# Lowering running process disk i/o priority?

Tags: windows, performance

I have a standard desktop computer with a standard single SATA drive.

I'm experiencing a lot of lags in some applications, probably because of the disk (queue is often > 10).

Is there a way to reduce I/O priority of some existing non important process (in the same manner I can lower the CPU priority of these processes) ?

Comment: A good question - unfortunately I don't know the answer. My way to solve the disk queue problem was buying an SSD ;)

Comment: here, where I work, it's very very very hard to get hardware. Not for its cost, but for the processes of buying. Plus the wish of standardized hardware. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O prioritization is new in Vista; which version are you running? The TaskManager process priority will also affect I/O priority: Low priority processes (threads) will have their I/O requests executed after all other I/O requests are finished.

Comment: Win 7 & win 2K8 R2

Comment: @SteveB: In that case, high-priority threads also have high I/O priority. But it sounds like you already tried modifying the priorities, so this probably won't yield further benefits. Robert is right: SSD's have made software hacks utterly redundant.

Comment: I feel you are right. SSD is the solution. Unfortunately, as I said, getting hardware here is far from possible. I'll spread some seed. Maybe of them will grow up, and the next desktop generation will have ssd by default.

Comment: A little late to the party but taking this a step further, even a `Low` process priority doesn't make any appreciable difference on my system, however `Background` priority does actually force that app the back of the disk I/O queue. This priority can be set via [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and other similar tools

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 simply reducing the process priority in Task Manager doesn't change its disk IO priority. You need to use some tools like https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer