# HDD usage management solution

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems, file-management

It is really difficult to let some big file copy to somewhere in background while you are using some software in parallel to save time but because of high HDD usage by the process that is copying the file, the software lags a lot during that time.

Is there any way to control what process gets what %age of HDD max speed?

I am using Windows 10, but answers for other Operating systems are welcome.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/434214/lowering-running-process-disk-i-o-priority Change the process priority (eg via task manger)  of the thing that  is lagging to get more disk priority

Answer (score 1):

Copying large files in Windows using Explorer is always inefficient and it will always slow down computer while the operation is running. The reason for that is the default copy method, which involves Windows Swap File. That way it not only jams the SATA channel but also bogs down system and subsequently any application running will also be slow or outright unresponsive.

Solution is to use 3rd party software for copying files (not only large... all). My all time favourite is Total Commander (how favourite you might ask? Well, I started using it when it was Windows Commander 0.85 I think). This program has a lot of options for copying operations. I'm using "big files" option whenever I'm working with a computer with HDD.

Of course all that is eliminated by using SSD, which I recommend strongly in any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux there is IONICE, and [have a look at this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208/windows-equivalent-of-nice) for how to set priorities in Windows(ie the "start" command will let you set a priority switch or other solutions - however you are missing something in your logic.

Hard drives have very high latency (because of the time the platter and head take to move to the correct place), thus when doing multiple tasks, the maximum speed of the drive is a lot higher then the maximum speed you will achieve with lots of jumping around the disk as opposed to sequential reads which are typically faster).

Comment: For when the user will need max speed, they may not refer to this question, this question takes in account the time saving solution that does not care about maximum speed.

Comment: Say for example your file will take 1 hr to copy and you gotta work on some big software or maybe play a game for 6 hrs straight. Instead of getting the software slowed down, we can decrease the disk usage of the copy process so that it may take 4 hrs to complete instead of 1 but because of multi tasking, your work will still be finished in total 6 hrs and not 7 if we consider the other case where you let the file copy for 1 hr (in max speed) and then switch to work for 6 hrs.